# How to find the active page of the first pageinit in jQM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to get the ID of the active page element loaded by [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile).  I know that we can use `$.mobile.activePage` to get the current page in view and that we can get the ID of this element using `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')`. However, it is `undefined` on first load of the application.  In my particular application, I want users to be able to enter from any URL and I need to know the currently loaded page in order to properly initialise my navigation system

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() { 
    if($.mobile.activePage !== undefined) {
        console.log($.mobile.activePage.attr('id'));
    }
    else {
        console.log('1st page load detected');
    }
});
```

**Outputs:** `1st page load detected` on first load and the ID on every subsequent page.  How can I get the ID on the first load?!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your problem is, that **pageinit** is too early to query for active page class.

If you load the first page, pageinit will fire BEFORE the changePage to the first page is called (the first page is also loaded via a changePage call). Only @about line 3639 in JQM, the active page class gets assigned to the page.

By that time, pageinit is long gone.

If you want to grab the ID of the first page either use any other of the available [page events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html):

```
pagebeforeload = triggered before the load request (inside changepage) is made
pageload = triggered after the page was loaded
pagebeforechange = triggered before a changepage is made
pagechange = triggered after changepage is done
pagebeforeshow = triggered before the page is shown
pageshow = triggered when the page is shown
```

I would use pagebeforeshow, or if you want to tweak a lot of content, try pagechange or pagebeforechange.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes frequent is right. Pageinit is too early. I tested this with pageshow and it worked fine.

Comment: This is great info. I want to attach complex swipe navigation events to the pages... which is the best hook for this?

Comment: I'd go with $(document).on('your_swipe_event', 'your_swipe_element', function(){ your_stuff }); - requires Jquery 1.7.1, but binding to document ensures your elements get bound, even if they are not on the page yet (similar to live(), only supposed to be faster)

Comment: OK, you rock! I presume I can run some filters on $(this) within the event that makes sure the swipe is not on something like a form slider or or similar to prevent navigational chaos...? I'll give it a go anyway...

Comment: post back if you need more info. Also have a look here: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/ This lets you swipe pages or images or whatever out-of-the-box

Comment: Yes, I've seen that plugin, it looks great, but I want to build something more complex... I want to load a complete navigation tree into a JSON structure and use that to control navigation in 4 directions - left and right for parent pages, up and down to traverse subpages in the tree, who will also have sibling pages to the left and right... wish me luck! Thanks for your help, I will mark your answer as correct shortly when I've implemented your suggestions.

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` event is doing exactly what I need thanks so much for your help.